# Kotlin: Child Constructor Passing Default Value to Parent

Tags: java, kotlin

Consider the following classes:

```
open class Parent(foo: Map<a, b>)

class Child(foo: Map<a, b>): Parent(foo)
```

This seems to work here because the definition of `foo` are identical in both classes. However when I try to do

```
class Child(foo: Map<a, b>? = mapOf()): Parent(foo)
```

It no longer works because `foo` is defined as optional in the `Child` class.
This is giving me issues because I'm trying to initialize the `Child` class in Java and obviously it wouldn't allow me to selectively pass in arguments like Kotlin, so I was wondering what I could do here to allow the Java caller to pass in a `null` to the `foo` field so the field gets auto-initialized to an empty map.

Thanks

EDIT: Would also appreciate if someone could explain why Kotlin wouldn't try to pass the default `foo` value in `Child` to `Parent`? We all know `foo` in `Child` would definitely be nonnull anyway.

Comment: We do NOT know that! With this signature I can easily create a `Child(foo = null)` and the default value would not apply!

Answer (score 0):

The best option for a client of Child class would be to not pass any parameter instead of null, so you can just specify a default value for a foo map in Child constructor

```
class Child(foo: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()): Parent(foo)
```

then kotlin compiler will generate two constructors of Child class so you can use it like you want in java

```
Child child = new Child();
Child secondChild = new Child(new HashMap<>());
```

Comment: This seems to work well if there's only one optional param in question. However it seems like the number of secondary constructors would blow up as we add more optionals?

Comment: yes, but if you have more parameters then maybe you don't need this null at all, you can specify just default value of parameter foo in Child class and kotlin compiler will generate two constructors for you to use, i will update my answer

Comment: I'm curious as to what will happen if someone passes a `HashMap` whose value is null? Say `HashMap<> myMap = null`.

Comment: you will get an IllegalArgumentException in runtime in your java program, kotlin compiler will create constructor which looks like this (this is a decompiled version from bytecode)

`public Child(@NotNull Map foo) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(foo, "foo");
      super(foo);
   }
`

Answer (score 0):

> to allow the Java caller to pass in a null to the foo field so the field gets auto-initialized to an empty map

If you pass `null` (in Java or Kotlin, doesn't matter) it will be initialized to `null`. You can do something like

```
class Child(foo: Map<a, b>? = null): Parent(foo ?: mapOf())
```

instead. Or use [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation):

```
class Child @JvmOverloads constructor(foo: Map<a, b> = mapOf()): Parent(foo)
```

to create the overload without parameters. Actually, this is a special case where it isn't necessary:

> Note that, as described in Secondary Constructors, if a class has default values for all constructor parameters, a public no-argument constructor will be generated for it. This works even if the `@JvmOverloads` annotation is not specified.